# Prometheus query filter not working for OR filter

Tags: prometheus, grafana

Is there any issue with the below query?

```
kube_resourcequota{resource="count/deployments.apps",type="hard",namespace="test1|test2"}
```

It works if I pass just one namespace.

```
kube_resourcequota{resource="count/deployments.apps",type="hard",namespace="test1"}
```

Sum also works without passing anything.

```
sum(kube_resourcequota{resource="count/deployments.apps",type="hard"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [instant vector selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors) can be expressed as

- `namespace="test1"` to match label `namespace` exactly equal to `"test1"`
- `<no selector on namestapce>` to match all values of `namespace`
- `namespace=~"test1|test2"` to match label `namespace` with given regex

You made a mistake: you used a regex `"test1[test2"` with an exact match (`=`) instead of regex match (`=~`).

Correct expression would be:

```
kube_resourcequota{resource="count/deployments.apps",type="hard",namespace=~"test1|test2"}
```